# How to use AQDequeueOption?

Tags: oracle, advanced-queuing

I've seen a small number of posts that included code that used `AQDequeueOption` while dequeueing from an Oracle Advanced Queue, and I've seen some scanty JavaDoc about it.  I haven't seen any general information about it, and it isn't mentioned at all in the Oracle® Database
Advanced Queuing User's Guide, 12c Release 2 (12.2).

Can anybody point me to some explanatory information about it?  For example, is it only provided as an argument to `dequeue`, or can it also be used in other ways, for example, with a `QueueReceiver` somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually `Dequeue Options` specify how you want to walk-through the queue, as described https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14257/aq_opers.htm#i1006951 - Dequeue Options. `AQDequeueOption` materializes this concept on JDBC Api and can only be applied on `dequeue` method.

`QueueReceiver` is from another API, the `javax.jms`. In order to achieve the same result as using a Dequeue Option, you need to select the proper interface that has the desired behavior, e.g, `QueueBrowser` or `QueueReceiver`. (https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/QueueBrowser.html)